# How do I get to the Cloning Room?

Tags: paranoia-happiness-is-mandatory

The current mission where you start destroying PAL is followed by a "Go to the cloning room".... I just can't find it.

After I cross the Energy section of the map, I reach a closed door, so, how am I suppose to keep going?

[image: closed door]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's treason.

Comment: @RobertColumbia ,  I don't think you noticed but you don't get to vote! Friendly Computer will take care of everything. Questioning Friendly Computer choices is treason!

Comment: @RobertColumbia does not in fact get to vote, but the reason is because he doesn't have 3,000 reputation, not because of Friendly Computer somehow breaching the fourth wall and attacking Arqade.

Comment: Damit!!! After watching [this video](https://youtu.be/9mWDeBmHBXo?list=PLzoE_8icLV36oY5tnMDuBMzpMkERf5cav&t=1547) I noticed that it might be a bug in my game! The place this guy are heading is totally different from where I am and I just can't enter this place he's entering.